# Mac OS: get full control of web-camera (USB connected)

Tags: macos, camera, settings, driver

**The task:**

OS: Mac OS X 10.9 +

Description:

- There is web-camera connected to a Mac via USB. I need to discover a way of getting access to its' brightness, pan, color temperature, focus, etc.
- I also need a way to apply image filters against camera's video stream.
- I need to be able to control the camera while it is being used by other programs like Skype, so I can transmit for example video stream with increased contrast at Skype video call.
- Reference app: https://itunes.apple.com/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12

Solution:

This is the question.

As far as I understood I must to find custom kext (driver) in order to perform all this magic.

Could you please show me right direction, libraries, drivers, etc.

Comment: I'm surprised by the lack of conversation around this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv library to capture camera frames, apply filters, etc.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

Then you can feed a virtual cam that can feed into Skype, etc.
http://download.cnet.com/Virtual-Webcam/3000-2348_4-75754338.html
There also many open source virtual webcam available.
I hope this helps.